# Providing Speech Channel Secret in the Microsoft botframework Android Virtual Assistant Client

Tags: java, android, botframework

I am trying to run android Virtual Assistant Client of the Microsoft botframework from https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/solutions/android/VirtualAssistantClient.

When I run it, it always keeps on saying "Reconnecting to server" without doing anything else. There is a microphone button which on pressing says I am listening but does nothing.

In the readme they have suggested to add Speech Channel secret to the DefaultConfiguration.java. There is no such variable defined in the DefaultConfiguration.java file.

I believe that we need to provide this directline speech channel secret somewhere for this sample client to run properly but could not find a place to add that.

Note, my Bot is running on the emulator as well as on the Web chat using directline speech. Thanks

Comment: Did you post this? https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/1705

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some research into this and it looks like you've discovered a bug in that solution. [You can see in the code](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/solutions/android/VirtualAssistantClient/directlinespeech/src/main/java/com/microsoft/bot/builder/solutions/directlinespeech/SpeechSdk.java#L141) where a `BotConnectorConfig` is created from a secret key but `configuration.botId` is used instead.

> ```
> BotConnectorConfig botConfig = BotConnectorConfig.fromSecretKey(
>         configuration.botId,
>         configuration.serviceKey,
>         configuration.serviceRegion);
> ```

The documentation for [`BotConnectorConfig.fromSecretKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.dialog.botconnectorconfig.fromsecretkey) confirms that it should be using a Speech channel secret key and not a bot ID. That's consistent with how other client applications work. In Web Chat, you just need a Direct Line secret and that will allow you to connect to a specific bot without needing to provide the bot ID.

For now, just provide your Speech channel secret in DefaultConfiguration.java as the `BOT_ID` field.